# ESP8266 and Arduino, using i2s and the built in adc?

Tags: esp8266

I've done some extensive googling but haven't found any kind of proper documentation. Is it possible to use i2s with the built-in ADC on an esp8266 to sample audio? 
And if so: any sample code on how to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by using i2s with the ADC? Do you mean you want to turn the ESP8266 into an I2S audio ADC to sample audio and send it out to some other I2S device? Why waste an ESP8266 on this (especially as the ADC is utter rubbish)?

Comment: I want to use the built in adc and use i2s to get a constant sampling rate, as I'm going to just need it for beat detection. (if you have any other suggestion how to get a constant sampling rate, i'm really up for it. determining how many microseconds have passed (which was suggested to me before) is not really one of them :/

Comment: Just use a timer. I'm not that up on the internals of the ESP8266's peripherals, but most MCUs allow you to use a timer as the sample trigger to the ADC, then a "conversion complete" interrupt to get the data.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the ESP8266 Timer only uses Microseconds, that's not fast enough :/

Comment: No, the ESP8266 timers use the clock frequency. 80MHz by default, which is a resolution of 12ns

Comment: every code I have so far seen uses `void os_timer_arm(ETSTimer  *ptimer,  uint32_t  milliseconds, bool repeat_flag);` which means it uses an integer amount of milliseconds making the maximum timer speed = 1ms...

Comment: os_timer_arm is for a software timer. You want the hardware timer. But it's all a bit of a moot point because the ESP8266's ADC is utter crap.

Comment: how would i then use the hardware timer in software? and what makes the ADC crap? i _only_ want to do some beat detection kind of frequency analysis so i don't entirely care if the stuff is 100% accurate.

Comment: The results from the ADC are pretty meaningless if you have WiFi turned on. The noise is horrendous. You can use `system_adc_read_fast` to read a block of samples quite quickly. The SDK doesn't seem to allow you any real control over the hardware though. TBH the ESP8266 would be the absolute last choice for anything like this. Fine for WiFI, pretty naff at everything else.

Comment: SDK manual: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf